# upload picture to emulator gallery

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-gallery

I want to add picture in emulator's gallery. But i am not able to do this. How to do this? any clue! Though i have gone through a answer posted in stack over flow but didn't get success with that answer.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Check [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html#tasks)  Once you have a virtual SD card in your emulator, if you're not comfortable with `mtools` or if you don't know how to mount a loopback device on Linux (which is really easy by the way), just use `adb push` to upload your images. Possible example:

```
adb shell mkdir /sdcard/Pictures
adb push mypic.jpg /sdcard/Pictures
```

Comment: i got mkdir failed for /sdcard/photos, Read-only file system
@Felix

Comment: you might need to set write permissions too.  adb shell   ,  mount -o rw,remount rootfs / ,  chmod 777 /mnt/sdcard   , exit      then try to copy the image  adb push mypic.jpg /sdcard/Pictures

Answer (score 45):

You can also use the DDMS tool in eclipse to push or pull a file onto the emulator.  On a 2.2 emulator I was able to push some .jpg images into the /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/100ANDRO folder using DDMS.  I then had to go into the running emulator itself, select "Dev Tools" from the Apps screen, the select "Media Scanner" (or "Media Provider" in newer versions of Android) to get the emulator to recognize the files so they would be displayed in the Media Gallery.

Comment: Running the media scanner is essential. Without that step my emulator never sees the images. Great answer!

Comment: even media provider does not work, it does not refresh gallery

Comment: great answer, just saved my day here!

Comment: Either I'm blind, or there's no "Media Scanner" option under "Dev Tools".

Comment: I couldn't find it as well (Lollipop). You can run it from the adb shell with this command: am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED -d file:///mnt/sdcard/DCIM/100ANDRO/

Comment: @BenGroot, my adb shell is not recognizing 'am' as a valid command. Do I need to install another program to handle this?

Comment: @airowe, I believe it would be amd

Comment: @Zenadix - No "Media Provider" either?

My Media Provider crashes when pressing "Scan SD card" :-(

Answer (score 20):

First thing to do is to get the image(s) at the storage of the emulator. For this you have several options. I'll list the most common options here. But first an important note on the need to scan for this media on the emulator. As pointed out by Felby in another answer.

### Where to put the images

The standard location (for the devices I've tested so far) where images from the camera are put on the device is `/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/100ANDRO`.

However since we need to scan manually anyway you can put them at `/mnt/sdcard/Pictures` or any other valid path on the (emulated) sdcard.

<sub>The `/sdcard/` path is linked to `/mnt/sdcard/` so that will also work. I'm just mentioning this because I've seen this path on another answer.</sub>

### How to upload images to emulator

#### Using adb

For hardcore users, execute the `adb push` from command line. If you don't know how to work with adb I can recommend reading up on [this help article](http://cdn.cybersectors.com/wp-content/uploads/5_ddms-adt.png). Make sure you have the path set correctly for your system and `adb devices` returns at least one device (if more specify device in command).

```
adb push /path/to/image.jpg /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/100ANDRO
```

#### Using eclipse (ADT)

You can achieve the same by clicking some buttons in ADT. Go to the DDMS perspective and in the file explorer select the icon on the top. Check image below for details.

[image]

[image linked from http://cdn.cybersectors.com/](http://cdn.cybersectors.com/wp-content/uploads/5_ddms-adt.png)

### Scan for media

An important step not to forget is executing this tool on the Android Emulator. If you skip this the Gallery will remain empty. Many thanks to Felby for pointing this out.

> I then had to go into the running emulator itself, select "Dev Tools" from the Apps screen, 
>   the select "Media Scanner" (or "Media Provider" in newer versions of
>   Android) to get the emulator to recognize the files so they would be
>   displayed in the Media Gallery.

Comment: Using genymotion I just had to restart the emulator after pushing the images - it worked!

Comment: I fixed with /mnt/sdcard/pictures and restart emulator..Thz..it's workked.

Comment: i select media provider then what should  i do?

Comment: media provider's 'Scan SD card' causes 'Dev Tools has stopped working'. Any solution?

Answer (score 4):

If you need any of the image then simply go to google.com from the browser of your emulator and search for the images as you like and click on the image. when it is opened select full size option of the image and then press and hold the mouse for some seconds, this will give you saving options. you may search the options into the context menu as well.

Hope this will help some-one.

Answer (score 3):

I can put images in my SD Card in this way:

1. disconect my phone from USB
2. using **adb push** command line with the folder **storage/sdcard** and not **/sdcard**, example

   > D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\platform-tools>adb push "d:\star.jpg" storage/sdcard
3. close the emulator and run again
4. I check in **Eclipse -> DDMS -> File Explorer** tab, and I see the image inside **storage/sdcard** folder

Answer (score 1):

scanning for media might stop the developer tools sometimes... if so push the files into storage/sdcard/DCIM folder using DDMS mode as mentioned in the picture above and just restart the emulator....

Answer (score 1):

I used this one, it worked for me 
adb push "C:/image.jpg" /mnt/sdcard/DCIM

then run Media provider (in developer tools)
:)

Comment: What is "Media provider (in the developer tools)" referring to?  I don't see anything like that in "platform-tools".

Answer (score 1):

you might need to set write permissions too. 
adb shell
mkdir /sdcard/Pictures
mount -o rw,remount rootfs / 
chmod 777 /mnt/sdcard 
exit
then try to copy the image
adb push mypic.jpg /sdcard/Pictures

Answer (score 1):

Still annoying, here's some instructions:

1. Copy files to emulator using adb

```
adb push MyPictures/* /sdcard/Pictures
```

2. Reboot device, which lets Android to check system for new media files

```sh
adb reboot
```

Then the files should show up! Super annoying to reboot, but that's the most reliable method I could find.

**Note:**

This scripts is *meant* to refresh the media gallery, but I couldn't get it to work:

```
adb shell "am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE -d file:///sdcard/Pictures/"
```

Comment: I think you should run this broadcast command on every **file** under the folder, the command don't handle the files recursively