# How we save image in gallery of emulator

Tags: android

How we put any image in gallery of emulator. I tried that one     in many ways , but i still failed to put a image in gallery of emulator. I am using       eclipse and ubuntu. When i goes in ~/.android/avd/ and tried to make dir of image      , but i really failed to do so.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151744/upload-picture-to-emulator-gallery?rq=1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Steps:-

1) Go to File Explorer (if it not there then add file explorer from `Windows->Show views->File Explorer`)

2) Push Images into `mnt->SDcard`

3) How to push? Click on icon(Push a file into device) on right side of screen in Eclipse.

3) After pushing file, go to dev tools in emulator. In that go to Media Scanner.

4) After scanning your images are display in galary of emulator.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But sir , i already did same step-> and when we goes through above step then i found a error " Failed to push the item and Null". So i try to remount adb , but unfortunately in terminal message" No command adb found". So i move to set the path by ~/.bashrc file. But again i am fail to do so.  Now i ma in deadlock condition. Please help me. I will really glad to you

Comment: I solved my issue. Main Problem is in my emulator connection. Thanks to all for your response .

Comment: In my case, it was Media provider

Comment: Dev tools keeps on crashing. It asks me insert albums count and on click to scan or insert it keeps on crashing. Hopeless..

Comment: Hi @MobileEvangelist same issue is happening with me. My DevTool keeps crashing while scanning. Did you find any solution for this? If yes can you please post here?

Answer (score 7):

**This only works on Genymotion (Android Emulator)**

You can easily do this by Dragging any image to emulator screen from PC and it will transfer from PC's path to emulator downloads folder.

Answer (score 4):

1. Start any emulator from `AVD Manager`.
2. Switch to `DDMS` mode
3. Select `File Explorer` in the coming tabs.. You can see the folders and files in emulator.
4. Select `sdcard` or `mnt/sdcard.`
5. There is a push icon in right top of `file explorer` window. Clisk that button.
6. Select your image.
7. Scan your sdcard in

`emulator -> devtools -> media scanner/media provider -> scan sdcard`

Done..!!!

Before all that, you have to provide **sd card support** to your emulator.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But sir , i already did same step-> and when we goes through above step then i found a error " Failed to push the item and Null". So i try to remount adb , but unfortunately in terminal message" No command adb found". So i move to set the path by ~/.bashrc file. But again i am fail to do so. Now i ma in deadlock condition. Please help me. I will really glad to you

Comment: @user1734491 have you provided sd card support to your emulator??

Comment: Is the image a large one in size??

Comment: after click on file explorar there no no push icon for inserting images in sdcard

Answer (score 4):

drag and drop the image file in the gallery it worked for me
then close and reopen the gallery app you will see the images

Answer (score 1):

one of the easy way.Simply sync google photos and you will get image in emulator

Answer (score 0):

**Just drag and drop from pc to emulator and you will get those in the downloads folder of emulator.**