# Android Emulator Display Image from SD Card

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image

Hello !! I am trying to write a very simple **android program**. When I press the `share button` on a *selected image* from the image gallery a menu pops up and tells me to choose between my application and the messaging application to open the image with. When I choose my application I want it to view the image in an `image view`. For the part that I already done is the implicit intent when I press the share button it pops up a menu for me to choose which application I want to use. The second part is the tricky part since the image is saved on the SD Card of the phone how do I access that particular image and how do I view it in the `image view` ? And I am using the `Android Emulator`.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: There is no SD Card in emulator.

Comment: I think there is no image in ur emulator's sd card

Answer (score 0):

first create an emulator having sdcard [then how to save image in emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892163/how-we-save-image-in-gallery-of-emulator)

for picking an image from sdcard u can follow [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507898/how-to-pick-an-image-from-gallery-sd-card-for-my-app-in-android?rq=1)

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, 
       Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 

    switch(requestCode) { 
    case REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE:
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                               selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();


            Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
            yourImageView.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
        }
    }
}
```

for showing that image in ur imageview [use this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224710/set-imageview-to-show-image-in-sdcard?rq=1)

```
ImageView img=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ur_imageview);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```