# Add image into android emulator gallery

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried to follow explanation in the following posts:

1. [upload picture to emulator gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151744/upload-picture-to-emulator-gallery)
2. [How to add an image to the emulator gallery in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29588124/how-to-add-an-image-to-the-emulator-gallery-in-android-studio)
3. [How we save image in gallery of emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892163/how-we-save-image-in-gallery-of-emulator)

`/mnt/sdcard` empty folder in this location
`/sdcard` empty folder in this location
`storage/sdcard` no such location
`data/media/0/Pictures` files added, but can't access from galley

`devtools -> media scanner/media provider` also I don't have this options inside my emulator.

Comment: I might be able to help you with this but I don't really understand what you are describing. Please describe what you are trying to do, show some code (not too much) where it doesn't do what you want, and explain exactly what is failing.

Comment: @PeriHartman I'm trying to add few images into emulator gallery, using Andoid Device Monitor, there is a path to navigate into, and then to push some images into it.. Please see the posts I was looking for before (Links above)

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. So you are able to successfully add pictures to the desired directory, specifically data/media/0/pictures, correct? The gallery program uses the MediaStore provider to find images rather than look in specific directories, and that is the root of your problem. In other words, you have moved the file to the directory and not updated MediaStore. I don't know if there's an app available to do that or if you'll have to write your own small program to do it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can send any file into android emulator via drag-n-drop action.
And then go to Settings - Storage and re-mount your sdcard.