# How to Add an Image to Android Emulator Directly or through Visual Studio (Xamarin Project)

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I currently am creating an `Android` application using `Visual Studio 2015`. It requires to have an image in the `AVD` to test the application.

How do we add image to our emulated `Android` device in `Visual Studio` (`Xamarin Project`)?

I have seen some questions and answers to do so in `Eclipse` or `Android Studio` (`Java`-based):

1. [How to add an image to the emulator gallery in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29588124/how-to-add-an-image-to-the-emulator-gallery-in-android-studio)
2. [How we save image in gallery of emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892163/how-we-save-image-in-gallery-of-emulator)
3. [upload picture to emulator gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151744/upload-picture-to-emulator-gallery?rq=1)

But I cannot find one to do it in `Visual Studio`.

If I try to use camera in my emulator, it shows camera error, cannot connect to camera.

[image]

So, naturally I am trying to find a way to just put an image directly to the emulated `Android` device's folder either through `VS` or directly.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, naturally I am trying to find a way to just put an image directly to the emulated Android device's folder either through VS or directly.

You can use `DDMS`.

1. Run your emulator with VS 2015.
2. Open `DDMS`:

[image]

3. Use `File Explorer` to find storage -> emulated -> 0 ->Pictures folder.
4. Pull your picture from your PC to this folder.
5. Restart your AVD, then you can find the file from `Photo` or `Gallery` app.

[image]

Comment: I manage to add the file in the mentioned folder using DDMS as you mention. Upvoted. But I can't seem to check if the picture is really there. When I opened the gallery, it does not show the picture. Any idea?

Comment: @Ian, Have you restarted your emulator? First time when I put a picture into it, I cannot see it from gallery, but after I close and reopen this emulator, you can find it by gallery or photo.

Comment: It works. I restarted my emulator. At first, the picture still didn't appear. But after sometimes, it appeared as it should. It seems to take some times for the simulator to catch up with the update in the folder. Thanks!