# Xamarin Forms: Write a file in Android device's internal storage

Tags: android, file, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am developing a cross-platform app using Xamarin Forms PCL project. In this I need to write a file in Android's internal storage so that I can access it. I have given Write to External Storage permissions but when I try to write the file it says Access is denied.

Here is what I tried:

```
Java.IO.File DataDirectoryPath = Android.OS.Environment.DataDirectory;
string dirPath = DataDirectoryPath.AbsolutePath + "/MyFolder";
bool exists = Directory.Exists(dirPath);
string filepath = dirPath + "/test.txt";
if (!exists)
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath);
    if (!File.Exists(filepath))
    {
        File.Create(filepath).Dispose();
        using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(filepath))
        {
            tw.WriteLine("The very first line!");
            tw.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is generally recommended (and secure) to use app's sandbox to store files. If you store file in to device storage instead your file can be modified / deleted easily...

Comment: `Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath);` Should not you check return value? Or check if the directory exists before trying to put a file in it?

Comment: on that particular line it says "Access is denied"

Comment: For use of internal storage you do not need any permission at all.

Comment: Android version?

Comment: `I have given Write to External Storage permissions` What are the things you did exactly?

Comment: If you run your code again and the directory exists, the code to create a file is not executed. Intentionally?

Comment: `dirPath + "/test.txt"` You have that three times. Bad coding. Do it only once and use on following places. string filePath = dirPath + "/test.txt"

Comment: android Version is 4.4.4 and by `I have given Write to External Storage permissions` I mean in android manifest file I have allowed WRITE.EXTERNAL.STORAGE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In this I need to write a file in android's internal storage so that i can acccess it. I have given Write to External Storage permissions but when I try to write the file it says Access is denied.

First of all, the permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` is for external storage, hence it doesn't work for the internal storage.

Based on your code:

```
Java.IO.File DataDirectoryPath = Android.OS.Environment.DataDirectory;
```

You used `Data Directory` for your writing, this directory is owned by system and there is no permission for writing to it, there're several discussions about this issue on SO, for example: [Data directory has no read/write permission in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998400/data-directory-has-no-read-write-permission-in-android)
.

So, as it suggested in the answer there, you can use `getFilesDir()` to write in internal storage, in Xamarin, it is [Android.Content.Context.FilesDir Property](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.Content.Context.FilesDir/).

**Update:**

I wrote some code based on your code, it should be the same, for example:

```
var dirPath = this.FilesDir + "/MyFolder";
var exists = Directory.Exists(dirPath);
var filepath = dirPath + "/test.txt";
if (!exists)
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath);
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filepath))
    {
        var newfile = new Java.IO.File(dirPath, "test.txt");
        using (FileOutputStream outfile = new FileOutputStream(newfile))
        {
            string line = "The very first line!";
            outfile.Write(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(line));
            outfile.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I also checked this file by DDMS, it can be seen under the folder: `data\data\yourAPP\files\MyFolder\test.txt`:

[image]

I just test Xamarin.Android project, didn't tried to use `DependencyService` for Xamarin.Forms, if you're trying to do that, just replace the word `this` in the code above to your android context.

Comment: Do you have any sample code to use this property. Please share.

Comment: @Sonali, I wrote some code based on your code, please check my updated answer. And if you find this helpful, could you please mark this answer?

Comment: I replaced `this` by `Android.App.Application.Context.FilesDir`. Is it correct?

Comment: @Sonali, yes, exactly, sorry for the late response, I was in a meeting. Just tested with Xamarin.Forms, and it works fine.

Comment: how can I see this file in device?

Comment: @Sonali, as I said, use DDMS, and check the file path I wrote in my updated answer, for DDMS, you can check my [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43538453/how-to-add-an-image-to-android-emulator-directly-or-through-visual-studio-xamar/43606792#43606792).

Comment: I have connected my android device in VS. Will it work for device also?

Comment: While Debugging I tried opening it but nothing is happening?\

Comment: @Sonali, maybe you can open a new case to ask about DDMS, but are you sure your device can be detected by VS while you debugging? If so, it should be found by DDMS.