# Android: View file created in internal storage

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, android-log

I have created an app using Xamarin Forms PCL project in that I tried to write a file in internal memory of android device with the help of [this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43931910/xamarin-forms-write-a-file-in-android-devices-internal-storage)

Using DDMS, I tried viewing the files that I have created but in DDMS I am unable to find the file.

In device physically, there is no such folder that I created.

Is there any way that I can view the files that I have created in android device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have correct write permissions such as writing to external storage

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

There are 2 main locations it can end up.

```
/data/data/yourpackagename/
```

or

```
/sdcard (with the data and packagename, I think)
```

But they can go into different folders, depending on where you write them.