# Writing a file to a phone's internal storage with Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to write a file to the internal storage of my phone using Xamarin. So far, I tried to follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/) and found [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43931910/xamarin-forms-write-a-file-in-android-devices-internal-storage) related question. My code looks as follows:

```
public async Task WriteDataToFile() {
    string PersonalFolderPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("PersonalFolderPath: " + PersonalFolderPath);
    var backingFile = Path.Combine(PersonalFolderPath, "count.txt");
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("backingFile: " + backingFile.ToString());
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(backingFile)) {
        var newfile = new Java.IO.File(backingFile);
        using (FileOutputStream outfile = new FileOutputStream(newfile)) {
            string line = "The very first line!";
            outfile.Write(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(line));
            outfile.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the debug output I receive:

> [0:] PersonalFolderPath: /data/user/0/MyApp.Android/files
>
> [0:] backingFile: /data/user/0/MyApp.Android/files/count.txt

After executing the code, I try to access the newly created file from my PC by checking the path "This PC\Galaxy S8\Phone\Android\data\MyApp.Android\files" but unfortunately it's not there. What am I doing wrong here? Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you see or access the file from your s8 phone?

Comment: You are looking for the Android method `GetExternalFilesDir` that returns a non-secure path that is external to your app's sandbox, and in the form of application package ID: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54126671/access-the-android-special-folder-path-by-using-environment/54127487#54127487

Comment: Although the debug output path is "/data/user/0/MyApp.Android/files", the actual internal storage path is /data/data/{package name}/files, in your case, the path is /data/data/MyApp.Android/files.

Comment: By the way, to view the file, first you have to add "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" permission to your manifest, then you have to root your device. As it is trivial to root the device, I tested using simulator and view the file with adb tool which also need permission, you can use the following command in cmd to grant permission before using adb tool: adb shell pm grant com.companyname.app android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: @SushiHangover Unfortauntely, the function "GetExternalFilesDir" is not available. "System.Environment.GetExternalFilesDir" doesn't work either. Is there any additional package I have to use here?

Comment: @Hagbard The methods exists on a context instance (Android application, activity, etc...) https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)

Comment: @AbbyWang You do NOT have to root the device, you need no perms, etc.... to access the files in your "app's external dir" (`GetExternalFilesDir`)

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks for your advice. I guessed OP wanted to view the internal storage using System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal. Maybe I misunderstood it.