# Can`t find mnt/sdcard in Android device monitor

Tags: android, file, android-studio, emulation, ddms

I want to push an image in gallery but can`t find`mnt/sdcard` folder as shown in this image:

[image]

Comment: there will be data folder and in that appplication package will be there and your file will be present there

Comment: can you give more details after gone to data where to go ?

Comment: Make sure that you first select the device on right hand side, and then go to mnt-->sdcard. Because the only way to refresh file explorer is to select the device and reopen mnt folder

Comment: Heyy @userr12 if you have already downloaded an image in emulator, then just go to this location "data-->media-->0". "0" folder will contains all your images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check below image,

> Tools -- Android -- Android Device Monitor

In that, select emulator and on right side move to folder

> **data -- data -- your application package name -- it will show your 
>   files**

[image]

Comment: I did this but still can`t find mnt/sdcard folder to push an image to it so it can appears into gallary

Comment: if you want to push image than on right top corner there is icon for push a file on device. browse from that and you will get it.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29588124/how-to-add-an-image-to-the-emulator-gallery-in-android-studio and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151744/upload-picture-to-emulator-gallery

Comment: Yes  it helped me alot , i changed the way of thinking instead of getting photo from gallery i get them from downloads by using this code       Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
but still have a small problem in that , anyway thank you.

Comment: Done @Amit Vaghela

Answer (score 1):

see `/storage` folder. This is the sdcard in emulator.

Comment: Right there is sdcard folder there but can`t push on it it said permission denied read only